# How to pass a reference to the main activity into the constructor of each subsequent activity

Tags: java, android, performance, android-intent

I have a class in LaunchActivity where i am initializing an object in OnCreate() .Now Clicking a button in launchActivity creates MainActivity . I am trying to access instance object created in LaunchActivity in MainActivity.

This is LaunchActivity

```
LaunchActivity extends Activity
{
    public static ABConnection abcConnection;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
abcConnection = new ABConnection(this);
}

public void Button_Click(View v)
{
 Intent myintent=new Intent(LaunchPage.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(myintent);
}
```

So i am creating a constructor in  MainActivity like this ,

private  LaunchPage launchpage;

```
public MainActivity(LaunchPage launchpage)
    {
        this.launchpage=launchpage;
    }
```

and then i am trying to access MainActivity's  instance object as `LaunchPage.Object.Method.`

But on execution i am receiving the following error -Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get package info for com.example.XXX; is package not installed?

Comment: Do you have MainActivity in your manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to access instance object created in LaunchActivity in MainActivity.

You do not have an "instance object" in `LaunchActivity`. You have a static data member in `LaunchActivity`.

To access a static data member defined on `LaunchActivity` from `MainActivity`, simply use `LaunchActivity.nameOfYourStaticDataMember`. In this case, that would be `LaunchActivity.abcConnection`.

In this case, using a static data member is perhaps not wise, as depending upon the implementation of `ABConnection`, you may be leaking memory, particularly your instance of `LaunchActivity`.

> So i am creating a constructor in MainActivity like this

That constructor is unnecessary and will prevent your app from working. Please delete it.